# A movie/film about a prince being cursed and turn into a bird?

Tags: story-identification, movie, magic

My Dad has been looking for a movie for a while now. Here's what he thinks he is remembering about the plot correctly.:

There is a boy/prince.

He is on a ship.

A storm hits said ship.

The boy/prince is then turned into a bird of some sort.

And there is a monkey.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info he can think to add.

Comment: Wait, so it's a film about a film? Or is that a typo

Comment: Any idea when he would have first seen it?

Comment: No its a film. He said he saw it in the 70's. Oh he mentioned that he was on a ship during a storm. And that there was a monkey with them as well. Disregard the goddess ansd satyr thing it's appearantly unrealated. The main thing is there was a boy/prince on a ship in a storm and a monkey is involved at some point.

Comment: Live-action film, or cartoon/anime?

Comment: You sure the prince wasn't turned into a monkey and an evil woman turned into a gull?

Comment: @Jenayah its live action i think

Comment: @KMo it might be. Tell me the name and I'll confirm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My immediate thought on looking at this question (and apparently K Mo's as well, based on an above comment) was that the film in question could be *[Sinbad and the Eye of the Tiger](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076716/)*, the third of Ray Harryhausen's three Sinbad films.

From the plot summary, per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinbad_and_the_Eye_of_the_Tiger):

> In the kingdom of Charak, a celebration is taking place for the coronation of Prince Kassim. But Kassim's evil stepmother, Zenobia, places a curse on him and turns Kassim into a baboon just as he was going to be crowned Caliph.
>
> Sinbad, sailor and Prince of Baghdad, moors at Charak, intent on seeking permission from Prince Kassim to marry Kassim's sister, Princess Farah. He quickly gets used to the city and its people, but finds it under curfew. When Sinbad and his men shelter in a nearby tent, one is poisoned and the rest are attacked by Rafi, Zenobia's son, but Sinbad defeats him. Soon a witch (whom the audience later learns is Zenobia) summons a trio of ghouls, which emerge from a fire and attack Sinbad and his men. Sinbad disposes of the ghouls by crushing them under a pile of huge logs.
>
> Sinbad meets with Farah, who believes that Kassim's curse is one of Zenobia's spells and if Kassim cannot regain his human form within seven moons, then Zenobia's son will become caliph instead. Sinbad, Farah, and the baboon Kassim set off to find the old Greek alchemist named Melanthius, a hermit on the island of Casgar, who is said to know how to break the spell. Zenobia and Rafi follow in a boat propelled by the Minoton, a magical bronze automaton created by the sorceress that looks like a minotaur. During the voyage, Farah proves to be the only person capable of calming the baboon. Sinbad has been convinced that the baboon is Kassim by witnessing it playing chess with Farah, before which it had beaten him, and it truly proves who it really is to a sailor by writing a sentence that says it on the wall.
>
> Sinbad and Farah land at Casgar and find Melanthius and his daughter Dione, who agree to help them. Melanthius says they must travel to the land of Hyperborea where the ancient civilization of the Arimaspi once existed. On the way to Hyperborea, Melanthius and Dione also become convinced that the baboon is Kassim. Besides Farah, Kassim enjoys having Dione's company and develops a love interest towards her.
>
> Zenobia uses a potion to transform herself into a gull to spy on Sinbad. Once aboard his ship, she turns into a miniature human and listens in as Melanthius tells Sinbad how to cure Kassim. Alerted by Kassim, Melanthius and Sinbad capture Zenobia. Unfortunately, her potion spills and a wasp ingests some of it. The wasp grows to enormous size and attacks the two men, but Sinbad kills it with a knife. Zenobia takes what is left of her potion, turns into a gull, and flies back to her own ship. But there is too little of the drink left: While Zenobia is restored to human form and full size, the lower part of her right leg remains a gull's foot.

Comment: Thank you! My dad confirmed that it's the correct movie.